# Why is an if statement stopping my bash while loop?

Tags: android, bash

Ive been writing a script for my android phone in bash and I just cant get the while loop to continue looping after my if statement. Everything else works like its suppose to and as soon as I remove the if statement the while loop correctly increments SEC_COUNT.

Ive searched the internets for an answer and cant find one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Heres the code:

```
sleep_loop() {  
SEC_COUNT=0  

while [ $SEC_COUNT -lt 10 ] 
do
        AWAKE=`cat /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake`
        sleep 1
        SEC_COUNT=$((SEC_COUNT+1))
        echo "$SEC_COUNT"

        if [[ $SEC_COUNT -lt 10 && $AWAKE = "awake" ]]; then
                ALREADY_AWAKE=1
                ALREADY_SLEEP=0
                echo "Sleep Interrupted"
                set_cpu_freq
                break;
        fi;
done 
}
```

Comment: You should be echoing your `$AWAKE` to see what that status is reporting since your `if` is coming back as true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `break` inside your `if..fi` exit from loop if

```
$AWAKE = "awake"
```

at the first iteration

Comment: So break will cancel the while loop even though the if condition is not met?

Comment: No, i think your condition is met

Comment: I guess I should have explained better or showed some more of the code, but AWAKE=`cat /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake` is only equal to "awake" when the screen is turned on. One of the conditions for the sleep_loop to start is the screen being off.

Comment: So what does `echo $AWAKE` say the status is before you hit the `if` since we know SEC_COUNT < 10?

Comment: Well, the echo is returning awake for some reason. So I guess you guys were correct... back to the drawing board I guess. Thank you guys!